# HTML5 redraw and post HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have three buttons in HTML5, `Add Circle`, `Add Text` and `Add Rectangle` which calls its respective javascript to draw that particular shape.Now, if a user changes its position how can get that new, changed position ???

Answer (score 1):

If you listen for "mouseDown" events on the canvas, you can store the mouse's position relative to the canvas' origin. Then on "mouseUp", get it's coordinates again and translate the selected shape to the new position.

Ok, that was the basic idea, for a more detailed explanation, you would have to do something like this:

1. on `mouseDown` get the mouse coordinates (relative to the canvas) and get the mouse offset (the mouse positions relative to the selected shape's origin)
2. on `mouseMove` get the new mouse position (again, relative to the canvas) and translate the selected shape to the new position, also you need to apply the offset previously calculated (you could use a [ghosting effect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback) here)
3. on `mouseUp` apply transformation to the shape (this might be optional, depending if the previous step actually translates the shape or not)

Have a great day!

Comment: I think you are explaining the way to transform/resize an object on the canvas, but i only want 2 get the x,y position of a shape ..